# Is there a Java data structure that returns a set of a specific attribute in a collection of objects?

Tags: java, collections

I have a collection of objects which are all the same object type.  Within that type there is an attribute that I want to access - in this case it's to add it to a comma separated list:

```
String sep = ", ";
List<Item> items = db.findItems();

for (Item item : items) 
{
    result.append(item.getDescription() + sep);
} //for

return result.substring(0, results.length - sep.length());
```

It would be nice if I could just directly access that attribute from all the objects in the collections so that I could call Google Guava's Joiner function:

```
return Joiner.on(", ").join(/*Description attribute collection here*/);
```

The kind of structure I'm thinking of is like a 2D array where each column represents an attribute and each row represents an object and so I want to be able to call either a specific row which returns the object or a specific column (attribute) that returns a collection of the attributes from all objects.

Does Java or a good third party have a data structure like this or would I need to create my own?

Cheers,

Alexei Blue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why don't you use Google's Guava to the fullest then?

```
Joiner.on(",").join(Collections2.transform(items, new Function<Item, String>() {
    public String apply(Item input) {
        return item.getDescription();
    }
}));
```

Comment: Should the return type void be different?  (In this case String)

Comment: Thanks Hiery and @andersoj :) Some funky looking code but works great.

Answer (score 2):

You can write an inner `Iterable` subclass that reaches into each object in a collection and emits the correct attribute.  See @Hiery's response, he got to the code faster...

Answer (score 2):

Comming soon in [JDK 8](http://jdk8.java.net/lambda/) with lambda expressions and method references

```
List<Jedi> jedis = asList(new Jedi("Obiwan",80), new Jedi("Luke", 35));
List<String> jediNames = jedis.map(Jedi::getName).into(new ArrayList<>()); //with metdod ref
Iterable<Integer> jediAges = jedis.map(j -> j.getAge()); //with lambdas
```

Depending on what you're doing you may even use the JDK 8 preview provided in the link.

Alternatively, the library [Lambdaj](http://code.google.com/p/lambdaj/) offers a way to do that.

Comment: Awesome, a bit like C.  I will need to persuade some higher ups to upgrade from JDK 6 first but I'm sure I can do that ^.^  Cheers for that edalorzo, definitely going to look into Java 8

Comment: @AlexeiBlue Good luck persuading the suits :-) In the meantime you might want to take a look at the [State of Lambda](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~briangoetz/lambda/lambda-state-4.html) where Brian Goetz explains how it works. The preview is still lacking some features, but it's pretty functional. Not for production envs, evidently this is for evaluation purposes ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Silly, but I would opt for Item.toString(). Doesn't there exist a map so you can do join(map)?

Comment: I don't think the join function takes a map, it takes a collection or an iterable I think.